# How to use fluent design and still support older Windows 10 versions

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, fluent-design

I want to use fluent design in my custom controls when it’s possible and still support older systems. How do I do this? This requires me to change my existing XAML-files, and when I do that it won’t run in older versions of Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it like this. I have added this in the App-constructor to add some global [resource qualifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/how-to-name-resources-by-using-qualifiers):

```
if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract", 5))
{
    ResourceContext.SetGlobalQualifierValue("Custom", "Fluent");
}
```

Then I created two different resource dictionaries, one for fluent and one for none fluent XAML. The files are named like this:

```
MyResourceDictionary.xaml
MyResourceDictionary.Custom-Fluent.xaml
```

You can do quite much with this. But to my knowledge it’s not possible to create custom resources based on new types like AcrylicBrush, even with [conditional XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/conditional-xaml) (at least not if you want to support versions before creators update). Instead I’m using existing resources like this:

```
<StaticResource x:Key="MyCustomBrush" 
                ResourceKey="SystemControlAcrylicElementBrush" />
```